# cmd not running jar file directly

Tags: java, cmd, jar, command-line-arguments

I have created a jar file from Netbeans with a scanner and a subsequent method in main. When I open cmd to run the jar file, I write java -jar [scanner input].
Now when I enter the scanner input, the program should run directly. However, when I do that it runs the jar file but prints nothing, then I write the same [scanner input] without java -jar and it starts to print.
I need the program to print directly after the initial java- jar . How do I do that?

PS. To make that jar file, I simply pressed clean and build on the project without editing much of the properties.

Comment: You need to supply your application jar name that is created after the build. It can be found in the `dist` directory: `java -jar MyApplicationName.jar`.

Comment: Sorry, yes I have done that as well. I forgot to include in the post. It still doesn't run immediately with the printing method.